# STM32F302R8. TIM2 como como output y TIM15 como input no me funciona

Tags: timer, stm32

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar la placa STM32F302R8 y tengo este problema.

El TIM2 está configurado con toggle output CH1 en el pin PA0. (Esto funciona bien).

El TIM15 está configurado como input capture CH1 en el pin PA2.

Tengo un puente entre PA0 y PA2.

El objetivo es que cuando TIM2 llegue al valor de CCR1 active el pin PA0, que esto ocurre, y al tener el puente con el pin A2 debería activar la entrada de TIM15 pero esto no ocurre.

El while que comprueba el flag CC1IF nunca termina, no detecta nada.

¿Que puede ser?

```
#include "main.h"

void mi_GPIO_Init ( void );

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    mi_GPIO_Init();

    while (1)
    {
        while ( !(TIM15->SR & 2) ) {}   // wait until input edge is captured
        timestamp = TIM15->CCR1;        // read captured counter value
    }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
    ...
}

void mi_GPIO_Init ( void ) {
  RCC->AHBENR  |= 0x20000;      // Enable GPIOA clock. bit 17

  GPIOA->MODER &= ~0x0000003;   // clear pin A0 mode
  GPIOA->MODER |=  0x0000002;   // set pin to alt function
  GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~0x000000F;  // clear pin AF bits
  GPIOA->AFR[0] |=  0x0000001;  // set pin to AF1 for TIM2_CH1

  GPIOA->MODER &= ~0x0000030;   // clear pin A2 mode
  GPIOA->MODER |=  0x0000020;   // set pin to alt function
  GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~0x0000F00;  // clear pin AF bits
  GPIOA->AFR[0] |=  0x0000900;  // set pin to AF1 for TIM2_CH1

  // Configure TIM2 to wrap around at 1 Hz and toggle CH1 output when the counter value is 0
  RCC->APB1ENR |= 1;            // enable TIM2 clock
  TIM2->PSC = 8000 - 1;         // divided by 800
  TIM2->ARR = 10000 -1;         // divided by 10000
  TIM2->CCMR1 = 0x30;           // set output to toggle on match
  TIM2->CCR1 = 0;               // set match value
  TIM2->CCER |= 1;              // enable CH1 compare mode
  TIM2->CNT = 0;                // clear timer counter
  TIM2->CR1 = 1;                // enable TIM2

  // Configure TIM15 to do input capture with prescaler ...
  RCC->APB2ENR |= (0x1 << 16);  // enable TIM15 clock
  TIM15->PSC = 8000 - 1;        // divided by 800
  TIM15->CCMR1 = 0x01;          // set CH1 to capture at every edge without prescaler
  TIM15->CCR1 = 0;              //
  TIM15->CCER = 0x1;            // enable CH1 capture rising edge
  TIM15->CR1 = 1;               // enable TIM15
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He movido la activación de los relojes al principio del código y he utilizado el pin PB14 en lugar del PA2 y ya funciona.